# How to make responsive two columns in a row? In first text, in second image in bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

How to make two columns in a row, one with text, second with image in Bootstrap 4 to be full responsive? I want to make a something like in this picture:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <div class='text'>
                <h2>Test test</h2>
                <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <img src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class='row'>
         <div class='col-md-6'>
             <img src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
         </div>
         <div class='col-md-6'>
             <div class='text'>
                 <h2>Test test</h2>
                 <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjVw9.png)

How to make the image always have the same parameters as div with text, to be full responsive?

Comment: do you want it to be the same height?

Comment: Define img { width: 100%; }

Comment: yes, same height for div.text and image

Comment: add this in your css        img{max-width:100%;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set image width to `100%` so that it won't be overflowed to the next block.

Check out this.

Since bootstrap uses `display:flex` all the blocks inside the div `row` will have same height.

```css
.col-md-6 img{width:100%;}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='text'>
    <h2>Test test</h2>
    <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <img src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <img src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
    <div class='text'>
    <h2>Test test</h2>
    <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Also a codepen: https://codepen.io/Ev1tw1n/pen/GPGvmd

Note: If you want the text content `centered` use `align-items:center;`

Comment: what if i will give padding for my text to be more stylish in a div? If i will give padding for my text, the div with text will be higher than div with img

Comment: You can align them in center using align-items:center; or set manual height to the image and use `object-fit:cover` to the image so that the image won't be stretched!

Answer (score 0):

add img-fluid class to both images.

or you can media of bootstrap 4 check below link.
thanks.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/media-object/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class='container'>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
<div class='text'>
<h2>Test test</h2>
<p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
<img class="img-fluid" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
</div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
<div class='col-md-6'>
<img class="img-fluid" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
</div>
<div class='col-md-6'>
<div class='text'>
<h2>Test test</h2>
<p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css

```
img{
  min-width:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fk04wndL/

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is useful.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


    <style>
 .img-section{
     width:100%;
        height:400px;
    }
    .text {
        height: 380px;
    }
</style>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
    <img class="img-section" src='https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/CreativeLandingPage/HP_Sept_24_2018/CR3_GettyImages-159018836.jpg' alt=''>
    </div>
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
      <div class='text'>
        <h2>Test test</h2>
        <p>Lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem pep lorem </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```